# Key cannot disabled!

Tags: keyboard

- Lately, I've encountered a pretty annoying problem of the key "End" (keycode 115 = 'End' ) always pressed and preventing me from scrolling websites as it's always scrolled down, I cannot scroll up or anything.
- I'd read already many problems and solutions about enabling and disabling independent keys on a laptop keyboard. I've tried running the command:
  `xmodmap -e 'keycode 115='` and `xmodmap -e 'keycode 115=NoSymbol'` but as stated from the previous threads, it will be reset at a random time.
- I'd even put one of the commands in a "scripts.sh" file and run it at startup but still no hope. It is still pressed when I've even already disabled it. Pressing "Page Down" or "PGDN" key will temporarily stop the problem for a short time. Is there anything else I can do to permanently and effectively disable the key?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem - is there gum or fast food fragments in your keyboard?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Never in my work had i use the "End" key on my keyboard, pressing "Page Down" or "PGDN" will help stop the problem for a short time, though. But still, i haven't been able to find a suitable solution towards this problem.

Comment: Run `xev` (from the `x11-utils` package), and look at the bit patterns of the characters. How's your keyboard connected? Check your cable, try another keyboard, try another computer.

Comment: Can you remove the keycap? If it's mechanical (PgUp/PgDn info), removing the END keycap (never used, you say) will change things, might help.

Comment: Actually, I can't. I'm using a laptop's keyboard @@. Removing the key is equal to removing the whole keyboard @@.

Comment: I am having the same issue. In my case it is pageUp key. It is so annoying my page is automatically keep scrolling up. :Q